# eBay's Browse API Example returns ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with GET request

Tags: api, ebay-api

I'm trying to get a selection of items from a single seller with eBay's Browse API. For the most part it works, but it seems to return an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error when I try their example for whitelisting sellers. Their example is shown here: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item_summary/methods/search#w4-w1-w1-w0-w0-parameter-name-filter-7 (under the "You can also combine filters" heading)

I'm using this URL, which is exactly what their example is: https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q=shirt&filter=price:[10..50],sellers:{rpseller|bigSal}

and it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried many, many variations of this and nothing seems to work whenever I add the sellers filter.

This is my current code (I've removed the authorization code for obvious reasons). I'm using Aurelia, but I've tested API call elsewhere and it still doesn't seem to work.

```
httpClient.fetch('https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q=shirt&filter=price:[10..50],sellers:{rpseller|bigSal}', {
    method:"GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer XXXXXXX"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, it may be that the e-bay API requires a JSONP request instead. You could try this by replacing the JSON call using the fetch client with the `aurelia-http-client`. Here is an example of what this might look like with JSONP:

**ebay-api.js**

```js
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class EbayApiJSONP{
    
    constructor(http){
        this.http = http;
        
        this.baseUrl = 'https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search';

        this.http.configure(config => {
            config.withBaseUrl(this.baseUrl);
        });
    }

    getProductsJsonp(){
       return this.http.jsonp('?q=shirt&filter=price:[10..50],sellers:{rpseller|bigSal}', 'callback')
          .then(responseMessage => { 
              return responseMessage.response;
          })
          .then(results => {
            return results;
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I couldn't get that working either. When I tried a jsonp call, I got an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET issue again, along with two `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Object]` and `vendor-bundle.js:1395 Unhandled rejection (<{"requestMessage":{"method":"JSONP","u...>, no stack trace)`.

I managed to get `this.http.get` working with just a `?q=shirt` query, though, but I couldn't get `.jsonp` working at all. 

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No problem, at this point it's difficult to debug without reproducing the entire scenario. Best of luck though :D